# Apache Hbase MapReduce job take too much time while reading the datastore

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, nutch

I have setup Apache Hbase, Nutch and Hadoop cluster. I have crawled few documents i.e., about 30 Million. There are 3 workers in the cluster and 1 master. I have write my own Hbase mapreduce job to read crawled data and change some score little bit based on some logic.

For this purpose, I have combined the documents of same domain and found their effective bytes and found some score. Later, in reducer, I have assigned that score to each URL of that domain (via cache). This portion of job takes took much time i.e., 16 hours. Following is the code snippet

```java
 for ( int index = 0; index < Cache.size(); index++) {

        String Orig_key = Cache.get(index);
        float doc_score = log10;

        WebPage page = datastore.get(Orig_key);
        if ( page == null ) {
            continue;
        }
        page.setScore(doc_score);

        if (mark) {
            page.getMarkers().put( Queue, Q1);
        }
        context.write(Orig_key, page);
    }
```

If I remove that document read statement from datastore then job is finished in 2 to 3 hours only. That why, I think the statement `WebPage page = datastore.get(Orig_key);` is causing this problem. Is'nt it ?
If that is the case then what is best approach. The Cache object is simply a list that contains URLs of same domain.

**DomainAnalysisJob.java**
...
    ...

```
public class DomainAnalysisJob implements Tool {

  public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
      .getLogger(DomainAnalysisJob.class);
  private static final Collection<WebPage.Field> FIELDS = new HashSet<WebPage.Field>();

  private Configuration conf;
  protected static final Utf8 URL_ORIG_KEY = new Utf8("doc_orig_id");
  protected static final Utf8 DOC_DUMMY_MARKER = new Utf8("doc_marker");
  protected static final Utf8 DUMMY_KEY = new Utf8("doc_id");
  protected static final Utf8 DOMAIN_DUMMY_MARKER = new Utf8("domain_marker");
  protected static final Utf8 LINK_MARKER = new Utf8("link");
  protected static final Utf8 Queue = new Utf8("q");

  private static URLNormalizers urlNormalizers;
  private static URLFilters filters;
  private static int maxURL_Length;

  static {
    FIELDS.add(WebPage.Field.STATUS);
    FIELDS.add(WebPage.Field.LANG_INFO);
    FIELDS.add(WebPage.Field.URDU_SCORE);
    FIELDS.add(WebPage.Field.MARKERS);
    FIELDS.add(WebPage.Field.INLINKS);
  }

  /**
   * Maps each WebPage to a host key.
   */
  public static class Mapper extends GoraMapper<String, WebPage, Text, WebPage> {

      @Override
        protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException ,InterruptedException {
          Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
          urlNormalizers = new URLNormalizers(context.getConfiguration(), URLNormalizers.SCOPE_DEFAULT);
          filters = new URLFilters(context.getConfiguration());
          maxURL_Length = conf.getInt("url.characters.max.length", 2000);
        }

    @Override
    protected void map(String key, WebPage page, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

     String reversedHost = null;
     if (page == null) {
         return;
     }
    if ( key.length() > maxURL_Length ) {
        return;
    }
     String url = null;
     try {
         url = TableUtil.unreverseUrl(key);
         url = urlNormalizers.normalize(url, URLNormalizers.SCOPE_DEFAULT);
         url = filters.filter(url); // filter the url
       } catch (Exception e) {
         LOG.warn("Skipping " + key + ":" + e);
         return;
       }
     if ( url == null) {
         context.getCounter("DomainAnalysis", "FilteredURL").increment(1);
         return;
     }
     try {
         reversedHost = TableUtil.getReversedHost(key.toString());
     } 
     catch (Exception e) {
        return;
    }
     page.getMarkers().put( URL_ORIG_KEY, new Utf8(key) );

     context.write( new Text(reversedHost), page );

    }
  }

  public DomainAnalysisJob() {
  }

  public DomainAnalysisJob(Configuration conf) {
    setConf(conf);
  }

  @Override
  public Configuration getConf() {
    return conf;
  }

  @Override
  public void setConf(Configuration conf) {
    this.conf = conf;
   }

  public void updateDomains(boolean buildLinkDb, int numTasks) throws Exception {


    NutchJob job = NutchJob.getInstance(getConf(), "rankDomain-update");

    job.getConfiguration().setInt("mapreduce.task.timeout", 1800000);

    if ( numTasks < 1) {
        job.setNumReduceTasks(job.getConfiguration().getInt(
            "mapred.map.tasks", job.getNumReduceTasks()));
      } else {
        job.setNumReduceTasks(numTasks);
      }
    ScoringFilters scoringFilters = new ScoringFilters(getConf());
    HashSet<WebPage.Field> fields = new HashSet<WebPage.Field>(FIELDS);
    fields.addAll(scoringFilters.getFields());

    StorageUtils.initMapperJob(job, fields, Text.class, WebPage.class,
            Mapper.class);
    StorageUtils.initReducerJob(job, DomainAnalysisReducer.class);


    job.waitForCompletion(true);
  }

  @Override
  public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    boolean linkDb = false;
    int numTasks = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
      if ("-rankDomain".equals(args[i])) {
        linkDb = true;
      } else if ("-crawlId".equals(args[i])) {
        getConf().set(Nutch.CRAWL_ID_KEY, args[++i]);
      } else if ("-numTasks".equals(args[i]) ) {
          numTasks = Integer.parseInt(args[++i]);
      }
      else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("unrecognized arg " + args[i]
            + " usage: updatedomain -crawlId <crawlId> [-numTasks N]" );
      }
    }
    LOG.info("Updating DomainRank:");
    updateDomains(linkDb, numTasks);
    return 0;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final int res = ToolRunner.run(NutchConfiguration.create(),
        new DomainAnalysisJob(), args);
    System.exit(res);
  }
}
```

**DomainAnalysisReducer.java**

```
...
...
public class DomainAnalysisReducer extends
    GoraReducer<Text, WebPage, String, WebPage> {

    public static final Logger LOG = DomainAnalysisJob.LOG;
    public DataStore<String, WebPage> datastore;

    protected static float q1_ur_threshold = 500.0f;
    protected static float q1_ur_docCount = 50;
    public static final Utf8 Queue = new Utf8("q");     // Markers for Q1 and Q2
    public static final Utf8 Q1 = new Utf8("q1");           
    public static final Utf8 Q2 = new Utf8("q2");

      @Override
      protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException,
      InterruptedException {
        Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
        try {
          datastore = StorageUtils.createWebStore(conf, String.class, WebPage.class);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
          throw new IOException(e);
        }
        q1_ur_threshold = conf.getFloat("domain.queue.threshold.bytes", 500.0f);
        q1_ur_docCount = conf.getInt("domain.queue.doc.count", 50);
        LOG.info("Conf updated: Queue-bytes-threshold = " + q1_ur_threshold + " Queue-doc-threshold: " + q1_ur_docCount);
      }

      @Override
      protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        datastore.close();
      }

  @Override
  protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<WebPage> values, Context context)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {

      ArrayList<String> Cache = new ArrayList<String>();

      int doc_counter = 0;
      int total_ur_bytes = 0;

    for ( WebPage page : values ) {

        // cache
        String orig_key = page.getMarkers().get( DomainAnalysisJob.URL_ORIG_KEY ).toString();
        Cache.add(orig_key);

        // do not consider those doc's that are not fetched or link URLs
        if ( page.getStatus() == CrawlStatus.STATUS_UNFETCHED ) {
         continue;
        }

        doc_counter++;
        int ur_score_int = 0;
        int doc_ur_bytes = 0;
        int doc_total_bytes = 0;
        String ur_score_str = "0";
        String langInfo_str = null;

        // read page and find its Urdu score
        langInfo_str = TableUtil.toString(page.getLangInfo());      
        if (langInfo_str == null) {
            continue;
        }
        ur_score_str = TableUtil.toString(page.getUrduScore());
        ur_score_int = Integer.parseInt(ur_score_str);
        doc_total_bytes = Integer.parseInt( langInfo_str.split("&")[0] );
        doc_ur_bytes = ( doc_total_bytes * ur_score_int) / 100;             //Formula to find ur percentage

        total_ur_bytes += doc_ur_bytes;     

    }
    float avg_bytes = 0;
    float log10 = 0;
    if ( doc_counter > 0 && total_ur_bytes > 0) {
        avg_bytes = (float) total_ur_bytes/doc_counter;
         log10 = (float) Math.log10(avg_bytes);
         log10 = (Math.round(log10 * 100000f)/100000f);
    }

    context.getCounter("DomainAnalysis", "DomainCount").increment(1);
    // if average bytes and doc count, are more than threshold then mark as q1
    boolean mark = false;
    if ( avg_bytes >= q1_ur_threshold && doc_counter >= q1_ur_docCount ) {
        mark = true; 

    for ( int index = 0; index < Cache.size(); index++) {

        String Orig_key = Cache.get(index);
        float doc_score = log10;

        WebPage page = datastore.get(Orig_key);
        if ( page == null ) {
            continue;
        }
        page.setScore(doc_score);

        if (mark) {
            page.getMarkers().put( Queue, Q1);
        }
        context.write(Orig_key, page);
    }
  }
}
```

In my testing and debugging, I have found that the statement `WebPage page = datastore.get(Orig_key);` is major cause of too much time. It took about 16 hours to complete the job but when I replaced this statement with `WebPage page = WebPage.newBuilder().build();` the time was reduced to 6 hours. Is this due to IO ?

Comment: add more code, it's not enough to see what's happening

Comment: sir, I have shared the complete code

Comment: some parts are still unclear to me, am I correct assuming you are building page rank by analyzing references between web pages and in reducer you load WebPage from store (database) by key? If so, yes, accessing storage in map reduce operations is an anti-pattern, you should only use data that comes into map/reduce methods. For tasks like yours you would split workflow into parts and intersect data in different parts to achieve the goal